# Chaining Promises while maintaining data (angular js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http, ecmascript-6

Ive seen that there are questions about chaining promises, but this one is a little bit different.
I'm making http get requests in my code. The first call returns an array. For each object in the array, i need to make another http call which returns another array and so on (this chains 3 levels deep).
The problem is, I need to keep track of which array element was used for to make each http call, and I dont know how to do this using promises.
I also want to end the chain by returning a promise.

I have the code for what I want to do written in nodejs without promises:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');


function makeRequest(options){
  var httpopts = {
    host: 'soc.courseoff.com',
    path: '/gatech/terms/201601/majors/' + options.p,
    method: 'GET'
  };
  var response = "";
  var req = https.request(httpopts, function(res) {
      res.on('data', function(d) {
        response += d;
      });
      res.on('end',function(){
        options.cb(response,options)
      })
    });

  req.end();

  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
  });
}
var classData = {};
function getCourses(m){
    var majors = JSON.parse(m);
    majors.forEach(function(maj){
        classData[maj] = {};
        var options = {
           p:maj.ident +'/courses',
           cb:getSections,
           major:maj
        };    
        makeRequest(options);
    });
}
var classCount = 0;
function getSections(c,opts){
    var courses = JSON.parse(c);
    courses.forEach(function(course){ 
        classCount++;
        var options = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(opts)); 
        options.p += '/'+course.ident+'/sections';
        options.course = course
        options.cb = buildData
        makeRequest(options)
    });
}
var sectionCount = 0;
function buildData(r, options){
    var major = options.major.ident;
    sectionCount++;
    if(!classData[major]){
        classData[major] = {
            name: options.major.name,
            classes:{}
        };
    }
    classData[major].classes[options.course.ident] = {
        name:options.course.name,
        sections:JSON.parse(r)
    };
    console.log('classCount-sectionCount '+classCount + '---'+sectionCount);
    if(classCount === sectionCount){
        writeIt();
    }
}
makeRequest({
    p:'',
    cb:getCourses
});

function writeIt(){
    fs.writeFileSync('./classData.js', 'module.exports = ' + JSON.stringify(classData));
}
```

EDIT:
I managed to get the promises to nest while keeping track of the data, but how can i return a promise that eventually resolves with the final data object?
My code:
Thanks four your help! I've managed to code it so that the promises work, my only problem now is in returning the final data as a promise

```
fact.factory('ClassFactory', ['$http',function ($http) {    
    var eventData = {};
        var promise;
        var courseData = [];
        var baseURL ='https://soc.courseoff.com/gatech/terms/201601/majors/';
        eventData.getClasses = function (event) {
            if(!promise){
                 promise = $http.get(baseURL).then(
                    function(majors){
                        Promise.all(majors.data.map(m => $http.get(baseURL + m.ident+'/courses')
                            .then(
                                function(courses){
                                    if(!m.courses) m.courses = [];
                                    courses.data.map(c => $http.get(baseURL+ m.ident+'/courses/' +c.ident+'/sections' )
                                        .then(
                                            function(sections){
                                                c.sections = sections.data;
                                                m.courses.push(c);
                                            }
                                        ));
                                    courseData.push(m);
                                }
                            )));
                    }
                 )
            }
            return promise;
        }
        return eventData;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly, each time you deal with an array of Promises, you'll want to use Promise.all in order to connect and merge your promises into a new promise. That promise will then contain an array of the results from each call. Nested Promise.alls can thus return Arrays of Arrays with all your levels of results as long as you use something like a map and a closure to capture the outer levels.

```
var fakeCall = x => Promise.resolve(x||Math.random());

Promise.all([fakeCall(1),fakeCall(2)])
  .then( 
    results => Promise.all(results.map( x => fakeCall(5).then( results2 => [x, results2])  ))
  )
  .then( x => console.log(x));//-> [[1,5],[2,5]]
```

The first array of calls generates an array of results, and mapping over those with a function that makes yet more calls will return a single result that can be paired with its parent.

Explicitly nesting things in this way will work for even deeper levels, but is not going to be pretty. There's probably an abstraction you can create using Array.reduce which can generalize this pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm still having issues returning it as a promise, I edited the original question

Comment: You still need to return the Promise.all itself I think. As the other commenter notes, all functions passed to then MUST return either a value or another Promise: otherwise all you're returning is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot some returns in your code. The function you pass to `.then` should always return something. Also you are modifying `majors` but then throw it away without using it. When working with promises - especially when they are complex and nested - it's not a good idea to modify any data structures contained in those promises unless you are sure nothing bad can possibly happen.

I would split it into several functions.
e.g.

```
var baseURL ='https://soc.courseoff.com/gatech/terms/201601/majors/';

function getSections(major, course) {
  return $http.get(baseURL+ major.ident+'/courses/' +course.ident+'/sections')
              .then(sections => sections.data)
              .catch(e => []);
}

function getCourses(major) {
  return $http.get(baseURL + major.ident+'/courses')
              .then(courses => Promise.all(courses.data.map(course =>
                getSections(major, course).then(sections => ({[course.ident]: {name: course.name, sections: sections}})))))
              .then(courses => angular.extend({}, ...courses))
              .catch(e => ({}));
}

function getClassData() {
  return $http.get(baseURL)
              .then(majors => Promise.all(majors.data.map(major =>
                getCourses(major).then(courses => ({[major.ident]: {name: major.name, classes: courses}})))))
              .then(majors => angular.extend({}, ...majors))
              .catch(e => ({}));
}

getClassData().then(data => console.log(data));
```